# Change `href`s links via `onmousedown`,`click` events

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, yandex

Basically, when I do [a search](https://yandex.com/search/?text=test) in Yandex, I get something like this:

[image: pic].

However, when I right-click and copy the link I don't get the real link, but the junky one (the one which works as intermediate with the function of tracking my click before redirecting to the link I want).

I'm trying to code a script which removes those junky links. This is what I've tried:

```
function decodeURL(str) {
   return decodeURIComponent((str+'').replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
}

function getRealLinks() {
    var classes = document.getElementsByClassName('organic typo typo_text_m typo_line_s'); // gets any search result

    var cleanLinks = new Array(); // we'll store any clean link to this array

    for (i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        var html = classes[i].innerHTML; // we get part of the inner html of the selected search result
        var pattern = /(url=(.*?))(?=&amp;\w+=)/; // with this regex we'll match the url
        var match = pattern.exec(html); // attempt matching pattern
        cleanLinks.push(decodeURL(match[2])); // decode the url, then push the match to the array
    }

    console.log(cleanLinks);
}

function bindEventListeners() {
    var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li'); // search results have `li` selector

    for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) { // iterate every element
      (function(i) {
        lis[i].addEventListener('click', function() { // add a listener to the current element
          alert(this.dataset.cid); // each result has an id (by default between 0-9)
        }, false);
      })(i);
    }
}

bindEventListeners();
```

`getRealLinks()` gives me the correct links, but I don't know now how to "progress" to replace the `href`s of the search results with the clean links.

`bindEventListeners()` as it's called, binds listeners that will be triggered when a click is realized on the search result body portion. It will be useful to me to get the `id` of the clicked search result, just to let deviate the links to the one I need. For example, the user clicks the search result with index `3`, I'll do `var search_3 = getRealLinks()[3]`.

How can I replace those links you can see with the clean ones in JavaScript?

Comment: I've tried parts of [this code](https://github.com/Rob--W/dont-track-me-google/blob/master/contentscript.js) too, but it doesn't even work.

Comment: FYI: [Google search link fix](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-search-link-fix/cekfddagaicikmgoheekchngpadahmlf) : for Google and Yandex. Available for Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

Attach a `mousedown` listener on `window`, the topmost DOM object, and specify `true` for the *useCapture* parameter of [addEventListener](http://devdocs.io/dom/eventtarget/addeventlistener) to intercept the event at the very start of the capturing phase from `window` to the click target. That is, our code will run before the target's `onmousedown`.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Defluff yandex links
// @include  *://yandex.*/*
// ==/UserScript==

window.addEventListener('mousedown', event => {
    const a = event.target.closest('a');
    if (a) {
        a.onmousedown = null;
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: I'd been looking for something like this. This works for Google as well.